# Why does Resharper say, "Co-variant array conversion from string[] to object[] can cause run-time exception on write operation" with this code?

Tags: c#, resharper, string-conversion, covariant, covariant-return-types

This code:

```
comboBoxMonth.Items.AddRange(UsageRptConstsAndUtils.months.ToArray());

public static List<String> months = new List<String>
{
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
};
```

Turns R# curmudgeon-like with the complaint, "Co-variant array conversion from string[] to object[] can cause run-time exception on write operation".

Actually, this code works perfectly - the combo box is populated with the month values; what is Resharper on about, and what can I do to assuage its doubts?

If it's simply that the generic list may contain bad data, I won't worry about it - and if there ever were a problem, it would be easy enough to track down the problem.

Comment: I guess a way to get around it would be to use a `List<object>` instead of `List<string>`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The method `comboBoxMonth.Items.AddRange` expects an `object[]` parameter. `months.ToArray()` is `string[]`. A cast from `string[]` to `object[]` is valid, but if the method tries to modify elements of the array, you will get run-time errors. In this case it doesn't, so you can ignore the warning.

If it annoys you, you can use `ToArray<object>()`

```
comboBoxMonth.Items.AddRange(UsageRptConstsAndUtils.months.ToArray<object>());
```

It will return `object[]` and no cast will be needed.

Comment: What do you mean by *if a method tries to modify elements of the array*? Modifying an element already in the array shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: If the method tries to assign a banana to element one of an array of objects that is really an array of strings, then there will be a failure at runtime. People reasonably expect that assigning a banana into an array of objects will succeed, but it might not.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, I do understand, and that was what I tried to convey in my answer. But I think there's ambiguity in the sentence that states that modifying existing elements would cause a run-time exception

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Apparently I am not following your train of thought here. How is it ambiguous?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Runtime errors would occur if the function receiving that array would _store_ it as Object[] internally (while it's actually String[]) and would then try to replace one of the items on it by something that's not a String. Example: `Object[] arr = new String[5];` `arr[2] = 3;` is perfectly valid code, but it will crash when you run it.

Comment: @EricLippert I think he assumed that the function would convert the received arg to a _real_ array of type `Object`.

Comment: @Nyerguds I don't even remember what my train of thought was :X. Re-reading this now is pretty clear to me.

Comment: The API may have changed because `Method 'T[] System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.ToArray()' does not have type parameters` error: `ToArray<object>()`

Answer (score 23):

An example to demonstrate the problem:

```
void Main()
{
    Animal[] animals = new Girafee[2];
    animals[0] = new Zebra();
}

public class Animal { }
public class Girafee : Animal { }
public class Zebra : Animal { }
```

This will throw a `ArrayTypeMismatchException` at run-time.

R# is basically hinting you of a possible problem of the fact that you're assigning a `string[]` to an `object[]`, which is completely allowed by the compiler, but may lead to a run-time exception if an object, which shares the same base class, is assigned to the array of which already points to a different type (as in my example, we actually point to a girafee array). Array co-variance is broken in the meaning that it doesn't supply you with the compile-time safety you get with generics.

Eric Lippert talks about this in [*Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Two: Array Covariance*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/ericlippert/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance):

> Unfortunately, this particular kind of covariance is broken. It was
> added to the CLR because Java requires it and the CLR designers wanted
> to be able to support Java-like languages. We then up and added it to
> C# because it was in the CLR. This decision was quite controversial at
> the time and I am not very happy about it, but there’s nothing we can
> do about it now.
>
> Why is this broken? Because it should always be legal to put a Turtle
> into an array of Animals. With array covariance in the language and
> runtime you cannot guarantee that an array of Animals can accept a
> Turtle because the backing store might actually be an array of
> Giraffes.